# From Master page - How to find the clientID of item in Child page which may or may not be there

Tags: javascript, master-pages

I have the following setup:

1. Master Page
2. Child Page
3. External Javascript file

In the Child page I sometimes can have a hidden control called 'hiddenFoo'.
In the js file I have a variable called 'hFoo' which should contain the `ClientID` of `hiddenFoo`.

Now I know I can add `hFoo = "<%=hiddenFoo.ClientID %>";` to each Child page but I am wondering if it is possible to do that within the Master page (taking note that `hiddenFoo` is not on every page).

** edit with answer **
1. In my master page javascript I checked if 'hiddenFoo' existed within my content.
2. If this returned not blank I called the code behind to return the ClientID.

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
    if ('<%=MainContent.FindControl("hiddenFoo") %>' != '') {  
        hiddenFooID = "<%=GetHiddenFooClientID %>";  
    }  
</script> 

protected string GetHiddenFooClientID   
{  
    get {   
        Control hiddenFoo = MainContent.FindControl("hiddenFoo");  
        if (hiddenFoo != null) {  
            return hiddenFoo.ClientID;  
        }  
        return " ";  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the recursive version of the `FindControl` method, or pick one already available, like [this one](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/06/recursive-pagefindcontrol.html). After that in the master page code behind you can create a property like this:

```
protected string HiddenFooClientID
{
    get
    {
        Control hiddenFoo = FindControlRecursive("hiddenFoo");
        if (hiddenFoo != null)
        {
            return hiddenFoo.ClientID;
        }

        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

and call it on the markup:

```
hFoo = "<%=HiddenFooClientID %>";
```

Comment: Thanks, I can see how I should be able to use this - will let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a URL parameter to pass a variable from page to page. You will still need to declare the variable on every child page.

```
var hFoo = "<%=Request.QueryString["ClientID") %>";
```

From the master page, the link to the child page should be like this: "childPage.aspx?ClientID=XXX"